# Django names from models in admin dashboard

Tags: django-models

I have in django 3 models:

- product:
  codeP = primary key
  nameP = Char
- part:
  codePart = primary key
  namePart = Char

For this 2 i manage to display name instead of primary key with:

def **str**(self) -> str:
return self.nameP
and
def **str**(self) -> str:
return self.namePart

But i have another model process with:
codeP - foreign key from Product
codePart - foreign key from Part

There i want to display in admin lines the following
product.nameP - part.namePart
This 2 are from the first 2 models
I tried to use the same scheme but it doesn't work

What can I do to display this fields.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to turn your question into a MWE? Currently it is not very clear how your extra model looks like, and what the main problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You convert the related objects to strings:

```
class Process(models.Model):
    codeP = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    codePart = models.ForeignKey(Part, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.codePart} - {self.codeP}'
```